# ASP.NET MVC ViewHelpers and Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, view-helpers, onion-architecture

I'd like to create a ViewHelper to localize my ASP.NET MVC application. Something like this:

```
public class Translator
{
    private readonly ITranslationRepository _repo;
    public Translator(ITranslationRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public static string Translate(TranslationEnum translationEnum)
    {
        return _repo.GetTranslation(translationEnum, Session.LanguageId);
    }
}
```

Usage in a (Razor) View looks like this:

```
<p>@Translator.Translate(TranslationEnum.WelcomeMessage)</p>
```

Now the problem is of course, I cannot make the `Translate` method static, because I need to access the instance variable `_repo`.

How can I inject the repository into a ViewHelper so I can use it in a View like above?

Answer (score 3):

The responsibility of the view is just to transform the data that comes back from the controller to a HTML structure. Views are hard (to impossible) to test automatically, so best is to keep them as dumb as possible.

Instead of using the `Translator` in your view, inject it into your controller and let the controller call the `Translator`. This solves a range of problems:

- It keeps the view simple.
- It improves maintainability.
- It improves testability.
- It improves the verifiability of your object graphs (because you don't fall back on static method calls or the Service Locator anti-pattern).

Long story short, add a property to the controller's view model and return that to the view. Example:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private readonly ITranslator translator;
    public HomeController(ITranslator translator) {
        this.translator = translator
    }
    public ActionResult Index() {
        this.View(new HomeViewModel {
            WelcomeMessage = this.translator.Translate(TranslationEnum.WelcomeMessage)
        });
    }
}
```

And your view can look as follows:

```
@model HomeViewModel

<p>@Model.WelcomeMessage</p>
```

Comment: That's what I tried first. But I can't access the Controller property from the View, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Sandro: The view should know nothing about the controller and vice verse. See my update.

Comment: I see, but that's not feasible for this project. In some views we even use the Entity as model. Is this really the only way? I mean, this way it requires a few steps more than with a ViewHelper, and with a lot translations... pheew

Comment: Can you explain why this is not feasible? You can quite easily 'enrich' your Entity classes with extra data by wrapping it in a view model class. For instance: `new HomeViewModel { Message = "foo", Product = product }`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a late edit in my last comment: It's not feasible because it  requires additional work. Such as extending the model for every single translation plus assigning it in the controller. Combine this with lots of translations... that's not fun anymore.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the intention of your design is wrong because it violates the single responsibility principal. Why is a translator dependent on repository?

secondly, why do you need a translator, you can use asp.net globalization?
[click me](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) We should not reinvent the wheel.

thirdly, all the html helpers are extension  methods which have to be static.

so my suggestion is if you have to use translator, please refactor the Translator class, decouple the repository from it then create a extension methods from there.

or you can use globalization, it sounds horrible to start with but trust me it's not as hard as it looks.

```
public class Translator
{
    private static ITranslationRepository _repo;

    public static ITranslationRepository Repo
    {
         get { /*check null here before return*/ return _repo; } set { _repo = Repo; }
    }

    public Translator()
    {

    }

    public static string Translate(TranslationEnum translationEnum)
    {
        return _repo.GetTranslation(translationEnum, Session.LanguageId);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that an SRP violation? The translator has exactly one responsibility: It takes a key and returns a value for that key according to the logic of the injected ITranslationRepository implementation. I don't care if the implementation ultimately uses ASP.NET Globalization, a database or even a webservice.

Comment: if it takes a key and return a string, why do you pass in the repository? OK, you need the repository to retrieve the key, but it's not the responsibility of the translator.

Comment: Don't think of a database repository. `ITranslationRepository` is just an interface. I could have also named it `ITranslationService` or `ITranslationHelper`. I abstract away the retrieving logic from my helper, so that I can change it anytime.

Comment: @Sandro hi mate, in this case I think you can use setter injection. what you do is you need make a minor change of the translator. I have edited my post.